# dplyr rowwise with lag variables

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to fill NAs in a variable using another correlated variable as per the code below.

```
test <- tibble(x = c(1,4,3,2,5,6), y = c(2,NA,6,NA,NA,5))
test <- test %>% mutate(chng = x/lag(x,1))
for(i in 1:nrow(test)){
  if(is.na(test$y[i])) test$y[i] <- test$y[i - 1] * test$chng[i]
}
```

Can I do the same operation in dplyr?  I've tried rowwise but it seems that it doesn't recognize the lag function.

```
test %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(y = ifelse(is.na(y), lag(y,1) * chng, y))
```

Multiple NAs in a row also prevents me from creating a new column consisting of the lagged variable.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you won't be able to forgo any kind of `for` or `while` loop. Your operation depends on the iteration on the last row to be complete in cases of consecutive `NA` on the `y` column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just repeat the `dplyr` operation until all `NA` have been filled:

```
while(sum(is.na(test$y)) > 0){
  test <- test %>%
    mutate(y = ifelse(is.na(y), lag(y,1) * chng, y))
}

# A tibble: 6 x 3
      x     y   chng
  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
1     1     2 NA    
2     4     8  4    
3     3     6  0.75 
4     2     4  0.667
5     5    10  2.5  
6     6     5  1.2
```

I'm pretty sure this won't gain you any efficiency for computing time, though.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I guess theres not much difference between while and for.  The actual question I should really be asking is why I'm procrastinating when a 3 line loop will do.

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because in rowwise you are using lag on a subset of one row. Creating a new column of y.lag before you enter rowwise mode will work:

```
test %>% mutate(y.lag = lag(y,1)) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(y = ifelse(is.na(y), y.lag * chng, y)) %>%
  select(-y.lag)
```

Comment: This does not fix situations with consecutive `NA` in the `y` column.